# C++ Override Operator const char*

Tags: c++, casting, printf

I'm wondering if it would be possible or not a good idea to override `operator const char*()` to get a Java `toString()` like behavior, because the %s delimiter represents a `const char*`, no? What I mean:

```
vec3 a(1, 2, 3); // operator const char*() returns a string "<x, y, z>"

printf("%s\n", (const char*)a);
```

Expected output:

```
<1, 2, 3>
```

Now, yes, I know that it would be a much better idea to simply implement `operator<<(ostream&)` as

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& rhs)
{
    rhs << "<" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ">";

    return rhs;
}
```

But humor me, here. I have already written a block of code that won't play nicely with iostream, but will work better with the old stdio function. I already know about the benefits of iostream functions, like type-safety, efficiency, faster code, etc. In fact, this seems to be a problem of code-smell, so I may eventually rewrite it. In fact, I already tried rewriting it a couple of times to implement streams, but it is proving to be a massive pain. And so, for now I would simply like to know how to implement an overload of the const char* cast for an object.

Thank you!

Comment: I know that doesn't always immediately pop up in OOP programmer's mind, but in C++ you can define functions that operatate on objects outside of the object's class definition. Having a `std::string to_string(const vec3&)` that gets called like this `to_string(a)` is perfectly acceptable, and even has better encapsulation.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I had been considering using a toString method, and haven't rejected it yet. If there are no better answers and you post this as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it would be possible,

Yes, it would be possible.

> whether or not a good idea,

No, it is not a good idea. It is not a good idea because it introduces memory management issues that you have to deal with.

1. Is the memory object specific?

If the answer is yes,

1. How is memory allocated for the `char const*`?
2. How is memory deallocated?

If the answer is no,

1. How would you make sure that the string representation of one object is not used for a second object by mistake?

A better option would be to provide a function `toString()`.

If you have the option of adding it as a member function, use:

```
std::string toString() const;
```

If you need to have it as a non-member function, use:

```
std::string toString(vec const& a);
```

Than you can use it as:

```
printf("%s\n", a.toString().c_str());
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", toString(a).c_str());
```

depending on whether you have a member function or a non-member function.

Comment: So the problem here is in the allocation and deallocation of the returned object... so I suppose I will use the regular Java method of toString()

Comment: @R Sahu Putting the `c_str()` call in the `toString()` method would suffer from the same problem, correct? The `const char*` would go out of scope before it can be printed?

Comment: @Josh, `c_str()` is written such that the returned `const char*` goes out of scope at the same time the owning `std::string` does. It's okay to write `printf("%s\n", vec.toString().c_str())`.

Comment: _"I'm wondering if it would be possible, whether or not a good idea"_ You didn't answer the question. You answered something that was explicitly stated not to be the question!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right, I did notice that. The root of it is a poorly thought-out question. I can be a stubborn mule sometimes, and so perhaps I should edit my question?

Answer (score 4):

A `const char*` cast operator could be a memory management nightmare. Who's going to keep a reference to your `const char*` pointer to free it?

If you don't want to go the `ostream` operator overload route, is there any reason you can't implement a `std::string toString() const` method, or a `std::string toString(const vec3&)` free function? You're going to have to add the `(const char*)` part every time you want to print it, might as well do `.toString().c_str()` instead.

Comment: OK, thank you. This appears to be the part I was confused about. To return a const char* from this cast, you would have to allocate it with a `new` or it would go out of scope as soon as the function returned, correct? That would be why my current implementation returns ???????????????????????????????????????????